# C# Excel: Union throw exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm currently trying to combine 2 ranges within a single workbook by using a union. However, the stated exception is being thrown by using the union. I've searched around but was suggested that the error is thrown due to using old Excel file but I am working on Excel 2017 (xlsx).

Test Code:

```
Workbook currBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorkbook();
Range desti = currBook.Worksheets[1].UsedRange;
Range src = currBook.Worksheets[2].UsedRange;

Range r = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Union(desti, src);
```

The testing workbook contains only 2 sheets like

```
Sheet 1 | Sheet 2
------- |--------
1  A    |1 Hello
2  B    |2 Bye
3  C    |3 Hello
9  D    |4 Bye
10 E    |5 Hello
11 F    |6 Bye
```

where each sheet only takes up 2 columns.

Comment: Union works on one worksheet only.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot create a union range of ranges from different sheets.

Comment: i see. thanks for answering. please response as an answer so that i can select it as answer for other people who faces the same issue.